What shell does GitHub Actions use?
If I have something like this in a job on GitHub Actions as part of my workflow,
run: |
  echo this >> that
  echo the other

what shell does GitHub Actions use?

GitHub Actions uses different shells depending on the OS that is mentioned in the runs-on field. You can refer to this article to learn more about shells. If this doesn't answer your question, please add more detail by editing your question.

@Ajay I answered it below. Thanks though.

@Ajay I don't normally read dev.to, but that blog is pretty solid.

Default Shells for Windows, and non-Windows

On Windows it sources pwsh.
On other platforms it sources an sh derivative, but bash firstly if the runner provides it.

Source: The Runner's ScriptHandler.cs
